# ElasticSearch filter by value in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have nested array of objects.
How can I filter by specific value in array? I want filter by reg = region1 and value greater than 2

```
{
  "region": [
    {
      "reg": "region1",
      "val": 2
    },
    {
      "reg": "region2",
      "val": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are your nested field really called `region1` and `region2` or is it a typo?

Comment: Could you add some sample of your data?